# PHP (Windows and Linux) - Getting Host names based on IP Address

Tags: php, networking, dns, host, lan

Sometimes when I call gethostbyaddr() it returns the correct Host-name, however sometimes it returns the IP Address, which I know it's designed to do when the call fails to resolve the Host-name.

It is absolutely **crucial** that I get the Host-names as all the IP address's are Dynamic (2 day lease) so I need the Host-name so that I can have a valid Primary Key when I save the Host-name and IP pair to a database. I literally have 2 printers and 2 computers side by side and one of each PHP can resolve into a host-name and the other printer and computer returns the IP Address.

How do I get PHP to resolve the Host-name for all devices?

Also, does anyone know how it resolves the Host-name? DNS? WINS?

I can run any tests on these two printers to check their IPv4 configuration if necessary.

Comment: If you have dig available you could try $host = exec('dig ...'); instead, but have you checked the nameserver and gateway settings of both machines? Do they match? The function works the same way for both machines, php works the same way, it seems the main difference would potentially be network settings on the machines themselves.

Answer (score 1):

[`gethostbyaddr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) returns the host name on success, the unmodified *ip_address* on failure, or FALSE on malformed input.

After checking the function on around 20 static ip assigned machines and around 5 printers it returned me the ip for machines and printers which were either down or were either configured differently e.g. a router or a gateway.

So, you need to check what policies are restricting `gethostbyaddr()` to return host name from your one computer and printer.